# Trying to heroku git:clone after heroku fork yields an empty repository

Tags: git, heroku, git-clone, git-fork

I just ran:

```
$ heroku fork -a oldapp newclonedapp
```

and it worked fine and runs etc. Now I want to pull the code down to work on it
[I realize heroku is not for version control and I usually use github for this but in this case I need to get the code from the clone] and when I try:

```
$ heroku git:clone -a newclonedapp
```

I get:

> warning you have appeared to have cloned an empty directory

and the new newclonedapp  directory is empty indeed.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, it's a [known issue of fork](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/748) that it doesn't clone the source app repository. Until the issue is resolved, you'll need to manually clone the source repository. Here's how I'd do it:

```
$ git clone git@heroku.com:oldapp.git -o old newclonedapp
$ cd newclonedapp
$ heroku git:remote -a newclonedapp
$ git push heroku master
```

Basically, you clone the original repo to a new app directory, setup the `heroku` git remote and push to it to populate the new app repo.

Comment: Looks like they've decided it's a feature. Wish they'd update docs to make it clear it doesn't handle this for you.

Comment: This is great! But it seems that when I navigate into folder `newcloneapp` (even when manually moving this folder to its own director), Heroku still required me to specify an app name. Any idea why ?

Comment: As far as I can tell from reading it, it is still a valid request and someone needs to make a ticket: the request is that Heroku will copy the source over on the server-side.

Comment: i got this error :`error: src refspec master does not match any` any idea ? thanks in advance..

Comment: @ErikReppen What if I have deleted my source code from git?