# Heroku thinks app is in same folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I referenced this awesome thread from the following to fork my Heroku app and clone the github repo to have two seperate github repo's and Heroku app's for production and development.

[Trying to heroku git:clone after heroku fork yields an empty repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751063/trying-to-heroku-gitclone-after-heroku-fork-yields-an-empty-repository)

```
$ git clone git@heroku.com:oldapp.git -o old newclonedapp
$ cd newclonedapp
$ heroku git:remote -a newclonedapp
$ git push heroku master
```

I then manually moved my folder `newcloneapp` into its own directory. Regardless, I still get the following errors:

```
 !    Multiple apps in folder and no app specified.
 !    Specify app with --app APP.
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, include `--app newcloneapp` in the command you are running to ensure it works with the right heroku application.

By copying the `newcloneapp` folder into its own directory, you are still retaining the git config for the application; hence the multiple heroku apps in this folder.

You can remove one of the applications by editing the `.git/config` file and removing one section with the `url = git@heroku.com:your-app-name.git` line.

In one of my heroku apps, I have the following config in the `.git/config` file:

```
[remote "staging"]
  url = git@heroku.com:my-app-name.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/staging/*
[remote "production"]
  url = git@heroku.com:my-app-name.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/staging/*
```

With this in place, I can push to both `staging` and `production` from the same repo. Looks like you need only one app in the folder; so you should have only one of the above sections.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful ! If I remove those lines in the config file, will it affect my ability to merge, etc. ?

Comment: If I understand your requirement correctly, you want one app in the folder. If that is the case, then removing the old section will not affect how you work with the new app - i.e. `newcloneapp`. From a different perspective, I think it would be a good idea to have both development/staging & production in the same folder (instead of separate folders for each), as it would simplify things greatly. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments for more info about how to manage multiple environments.

Comment: oMy question was how I could merge the development/staging/production if its in the same app folder