# Why am I getting an empty repo when cloning my keystone app to local repo from heroku?

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, git-clone, keystonejs

I first used the following link to create a new Keystone app from Heroku:

https://dashboard.heroku.com/new?button-url=https%3A%2F%2Ft.co%2FjbNu7UtZpn&template=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FJedWatson%2Fkeystone-starter

Then I wanted to clone it to my local repo:

➜  Nodejs `heroku git:clone -a yellowkorner`

```
  Cloning from app 'yellowkorner'...
  Cloning into 'yellowkorner'...
  warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
  Checking connectivity... done
```

But when I `cd` into the folder it's an empty repo, however the app is live online and working fine. Confused! Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the remote repo url of your local clone:

```
cd /path/to/local/cloned/repo
git remote -v
```

I suspect it references a fork of https://github.com/JedWatson/keystone-starter, meaning a repo in your GitHub account.

In that case, any fork done by heroku seems to be empty by default.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18766557/6309) to populate its content.