# Heroku clone creates an empty folder

Tags: heroku

So I am trying to learn heroku and yesterday from another computer I created an app. Today, from a different computer I am trying to clone the app (download the code) and keep working on the same app so I did this

```
heroku git:clone -a myappname
```

I get the message

> warning you have appeared to have cloned an empty directory

The app is running online so the code must be there.

According to the documentation this command does this

> This will create a new directory named after your app with its source
>   and complete repository history, as well as adding a heroku git remote
>   to facilitate further updates.

However, the repository is empty.

I saw the question below but I that didn't work for me. How can I simply get the code locally and keep working on this app without creating a new one? Thanks.

[Why am I getting an empty repo when cloning my keystone app to local repo from heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277465/why-am-i-getting-an-empty-repo-when-cloning-my-keystone-app-to-local-repo-from-h)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is counterintuitive, but looks like it is by design at Heroku. You don't copy from Heroku git to local drive, but the other way around - from your PC to Heroku.

You need to create or clone a repository on your local PC.

`git create <new repository>` OR

```
git clone <source>
```

then init your repository and commit code:

```
$ cd myapp
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in .git/
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "my first commit"
```

Then you need to link your repository with Heroku. Download their Toolbelt and run:

```
heroku git:remote -a your_app_name_on_heroku
```

And deploy code:

```
 git push heroku master
```

Hope that helps. I had to open a ticket at Heroku to figure this out. Check [Heroku Git instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) for further reference.